# Providing abstract method logic it always should have

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have this abstract class:

```
     public abstract class Base
{
    protected Timer timer = new Timer { AutoReset = false, Interval = 5000 };
    private bool _isTimedOut = false;

    public bool IsTimedOut { get { return _isTimedOut; } }

    public Base()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += (o, args) => _isTimedOut = true;
    }

    public abstract int Recieve(byte[] buffer);

    private void TimerReset()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Every time when the Recieve method is called from an derived class it should reset the timer by calling the TimerReset method. Can I allready provide the Recieve method the logic to reset the timer? So when I override this member in an derived class I don't have to worry about resetting the timer?

Comment: Did you try it?  Seems like it'd be just as quick to try it (or the concept) as it would be to ask the question and wait for a response.  BTW, I'm pretty sure you can - at least my 30 second test indicates you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `Receveive` function to call the `ResetTimer` method and than call another abstract receive function (`ReceiveCore`):

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected Timer timer = new Timer { AutoReset = false, Interval = 5000 };
    private bool _isTimedOut = false;

    public bool IsTimedOut { get { return _isTimedOut; } private set; }

    public Base()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += (o, args) => _isTimedOut = true;
    }

    public int Recieve(byte[] buffer) // This method cannot be overridden. It calls the TimerReset.
    {
        TimerReset();
        return RecieveCore(buffer);
    }

    protected abstract int RecieveCore(byte[] buffer); // This method MUST be overridden.

    private void TimerReset()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Microsoft's naming convention for these methods seems to be to add a "Core" suffix, for example for [`Control.SetBoundsCore()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore.aspx). (The implementation of `Control.SetBounds()` does additional work as well as calling `SetBoundsCore()`.)

Comment: @Matthew: I did not now that. Thanks for the advice. I updated my answer.